# Relay Module and Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am using a 1 channel relay module for arduino uno r3 like this(the picture shows 2 relay module but i only use one relay for one bulb), http://www.geeetech.com/wiki/index.php/2-Channel_Relay_module.

The bulb is 220V.I connected my arduino pins, D13,Ground,and VCC to relay module's pin; Input,Ground,and 5v.I also cut my bulb's wire to connect it on my relay's pin: NC,NO,COM.One cut end of the bulb was attached to the COM and The other is to NO.The other wire of the bulb leaved uncut.The source of the bulb is Direct current.

I uploaded the Blinking codes in arduino uno r3.

After uploading the code, Relay module followed the arduino's code which is blinking.The thing was, The bulb wont follow.I also tried dis arranging some wires but nothing happens.

I read some of the articles that would possibly solve my problems.I found out that they are using SSR.Is this really needed?and what could I do to make the bulb follow the arduino's codes.

I need Help. Please..help me

Answer (score 0):

If your relay is being energized then that side of the wiring is good, it's something on the other side that is wrong.

The output of a relay does not provide power, it is just a switch. You need to create a circuit that goes from power, through the relay, through your lamp, and back to power. If you connect to COM & NO then the lamp lights when the relay is energized; if you connect instead to COM and NC then the lamp lights when the relay is not energized.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram on that relay site is a little misleading. For your purpose, try running the light bulb from the +5V pin on the Arduino, to the NO relay contact terminal on the relay board, and then grounding the COM relay contact terminal. This should work assuming:

1.) Your wiring TO the relay board is correct AND sufficient enough to operate the relay, specifically, you can hear it "click" every time the Pin 13 goes LOW/HIGH from the Blink sketch.

2.) The 220V rated bulb can actually operate at 5V.

If the bulb needs more than 5V, simply replace the wire going from the bulb to the +5V pin, with a higher voltage battery (make sure you attach the negative terminal of that battery to one of the Arduino Gnd pins).

Answer (score 0):

The wiring diagram contains a lot more information than you need.

The relay module has a TTL interface - VCC, GND and one signal per relay to switch it on/off. These you should connect to the coresponding pins on your arduino(as you probably did).

Each of the relays have three screw terminals

- When you switch the relay ON, two of those terminals will be connected through the relay NO-COM
- When you switch it off, the relay will disconnect the other pair and connect COM-NC

The relay works as a switch, the lightbulb will be connected to the power as normal, but one of its wires(NOT the ground for safety reasons!) will be interrupted and the ends connected to the relay terminals.

BTW:

- Both the relay and lightbulb are limited in how fast they react to switching, the relay takes time to switch(cca 3 - 20 ms) and the lightbulb has a large thermal inertia. If you are trying to blink really fast(more than lets say twice per second, you might have problem with that.
- SSR are useful mainly for fast switching(normal relays have a limited speed) and should have longer lifetime, you can use it(it usualy has a 5V control input), but it seems pointless for a lightbulb.
- 220V light bulb will not operate on 5V
- Could you explain

  > The source of the bulb is Direct current.

Power plug 220V is actualy AC.

- What is actualy happening? Is the lightbulb ON or OFF permanently? Is it blinking in some wrong way?